# Div UI on top of input field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying add checked true to the input checkbox but I cannot click on the input because of a UI enhancement.

```
<div class="ez-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" name="AlertCB" value="ir-event" class="ez-hide">
</div>


$(".ez-checkbox").live("click", function(){ 
var findme = $('this').find("input");
//alert(findme)
$('findme').prop('checked', true);
 });
```

I started to write code to apply the checkbox checked, but so far no luck applying the check.

Keep in mind there is multiple check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ez-checkbox', function(){ 
  $(this).children('.ez-hide').prop('checked', true);
});
```

This will use `.on` (instead of `.live`) to listen for the click on `ez-checkbox`, then find the next `ez-hide` and 'check' it.

Comment: doesn't `.next()` only find sibling elements?

Comment: Oops, yes it does. Changed to `.children`.